# How to get filtered value of an item as line chart which is absent from column chart in combined chart in Power BI?

Tags: excel, dataframe, charts, powerbi, line

I have a dataset of sales values of five products: A, B, C, D and E in the form of pivot table for 2030 and 2050 which looks as follows:

[image]

I want to get combined chart showing A, B, C and D as columns. And E as line.
I select Year as axis, Product as legend and Sum of sales as series to get the pivot chart.

[image]

Initially, the chart looks as follows:
[image]

But using the combined chart feature, I select product E as line chart and get the required chart:
[image]

I am trying to do something similar in Power BI.
[image]

I also created a new measure `E_sales`:

```
E_sales = Calculate(sum(sheet1[sales]), filter(sheet1, Sheet1[Product]="E"))
```

However, I want to remove E from the column chart. And when I filter out E from column chart, the line for E also get removed. How can I fix this such that I have only A, B, C and D as columns and E as line chart similar to what I have in Excel above?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by creating a new measure that excluded product E and using it for column values, and using the measure that includes only E values for line values.

```
ProductExceptE = calculate(sum(Sheet1[Sales]), filter(sheet1, Sheet1[Product]<>"E"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice (and obvious) solution to the question, time will show if the original poster actually wanted something more generalized :-)